# DDD: How to properly organize hierarchy of subtypes?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am a bit confused how should I organize code base with hierarchy of subtypes.

To explain, I will demonstrate some *synthetic* example.

Let's assume we have some kind of **blog**, where we can have two types of posts: **text post** and **video post**. Text post can have its own **settings**, so do video posts. Also behaviour of comments is also different, so we can also have **video post comments** and **text post comments**.

To avoid *inheritance* with high coupling and use *composition*, let`s move all common things to some base classes, implementation would be *decorators* to those base classes with specific to that type methods.

For easier understanding, code for this synthetic example would look something like this:

```
final class BasePost {
    public string $title;
    public string $createdAt;
}

final class VideoPost implements AggregateRoot {
    private BasePost $post;
    private VideoPostSettings $settings;
    private array $comments;

    public string $videoUrl;

    public function __construct(BasePost $post, VideoPostSettings $settings)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function addComment(VideoPostComment $videoComment)
    {
        $this->comments[] = $videoComment;
    }

    // specific to video post method
    public function addVideoAnnotation(string $annotation)
    {
        $this->settings->addAnnotation($annotation);
    }
}

final class TextPost implements AggregateRoot {
    private BasePost $post;
    private TextPostSettings $settings;
    private array $comments;

    public string $text;

    public function __construct(BasePost $post, TextPostSettings $settings)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function addComment(TextPostComment $videoComment)
    {
        $this->comments[] = $videoComment;
    }

    // specific to blog post method
    public function addSeo(array $tags)
    {
        $this->settings->addSeo($tags);
    }
}

final class BasePostSettings {
    public $visible;
}

final class VideoPostSettings {
    private BasePostSettings $settings;
    private string $annotation;

    public function __construct(BasePostSettings $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function addAnnotation(string $annotation)
    {
        $this->annotation = $annotation;
    }
}

final class TextPostSettings {
    private BasePostSettings $settings;
    private array $tags;

    public function __construct(BasePostSettings $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function addSeo(array $tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }
}

final class BaseComment {
    public $text;
}

final class TextPostComment {
    private BaseComment $comment;
    private string $authorEmail;

    public function __construct(BaseComment $comment, string $authorEmail)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->authorEmail = $authorEmail;
    }
}

final class VideoPostComment {
    private BaseComment $comment;
    private string $authorYoutubeChannel;

    public function __construct(BaseComment $comment, string $authorYoutubeChannel)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->authorYoutubeChannel = $authorYoutubeChannel;
    }
}
```

The question is, what is more proper way to organize such hierarchy with different subtypes?

Should I group it by **type** or by **functional purpose**?

With grouping by type my folder structure would look like:

```
Base\Domain\Entity:
            BasePost
            BasePostSettings
            BaseComment
Video\Domain\Entity:
            VideoPost
            VideoPostSettings
            VideoPostComment
Text\Domain\Entity:
            TextPost
            TextPostSettings
            TextPostComment
```

By functional purpose:

```
Post\Domain\Entity:
            BasePost
            VideoPost
            TextPost

Settings\Domain\Entity:
            BasePostSettings
            VideoPostSettings
            TextPostSettings

Comment\Domain\Entity:
            BaseComment
            VideoPostComment
            TextPostComment
```

First one looks more appropriate for me, however there are a few concerns, for example, all common value objects would also move to Base\Domain\ValueObject, which would look very confusing

Comment: Difficult to say anything, because you don't actually have any behavior. You just have bags of data. It's cool that you want to prefer composition over inheritance, but your example is not even in the realm of oo at this point.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam That's the problem with synthetic examples, I tried to keep entities as simple as possible just to show the hierarchy of subtypes, so let's _assume_ that they have some kind of behaviour, what is the better way of organizing them?

Comment: You cannot divorce the design of the solution from the nature of the problem. If you're not trying to solve any particular problem, every way of organizing things is equally good.

Comment: What @trentcl said. I just want to emphasize, because it is vitally important, and very often ignored: **There is no design without behavior.** If you want to create a simplified example leave out the data (because that's irrelevant), and tell us what things are supposed to do.

Comment: By the way, here is an article of mine about exactly this topic: [Happy Packaging](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/happy-packaging/)

Comment: DDD asks us to design a system according to it's behavior! With this in mind, "some kind of behavior" turns out to be the key to unlocking how your system should be designed.

Answer (score 3):

## As a Lump

Seriously without more information about the domain, the best method to organise is to have a folder called `/Entities/` with all of the entities in it.

## By Bounded Context

If I had some more information about the domain, I'd start drawing little cordons around entities that tightly co-operate.

It's a matter of taste as to what tightly co-operate means. At the very-least its everything in the same aggregate root. But you could go further and include entities that must be known of in order to achieve some business goal X.

But there does come a point where including everything that ever is related by any business process together will bring us back to the lump. So boundaries are important, finding the ones with the right level of permeability is a trick in its own right, but it is the technique you need to use to figure out how to organise your entities better.

Once you've decided on those groups, each Bounded Context gets its own separate folder, if not its own separate library.

## By Their Graph

Entities in the domain form graphs.

At least some of those graphs are trees, and they layout nicely on a directory structure. Although sometimes a folder looks much better, having five files one at each point of the folder hierarchy is cumbersome. So is ten thousand files in one directory.

Otherwise there is a circle in the graph and the best you can do here is lump all of those into the one directory. Or pick a dependency and ignore repeatedly until you get a nice tree.

## By Fiat

Just organise them however you feel fits best. Its not like code cannot refer to other modules/classes/functions/etc... And its not like you will receive a speed or memory layout optimisation (okay, well some library formats do work against you here, are you in an resource limited space?).

You are trying to optimise for developer understanding, as the slowest operation this code will ever perform is being read and interpreted by a human.

Unfortunately the science has not really come through on this yet. There is no magic silver bullet that tells us how to do this, only that there are benefits for those who get it right.